# Асинхронный вывод данных в шаблоне Angular

Tags: angular2, angular

Я в шаблоне вывожу список товаров. Каждый товар отдельно шлется в запросе на сервер для вывода информации. Но метод parseValue ничего у меня не выводит.
Пробовала выводить асинхронно через `{{parseValue(item) | async}}` - выводит ошибку. Как правильно вывести данные из parseValue() ?

```
<div*ngFor="let item of cars">
<span>{{item}}{{parseValue(item)}}</span>
</div>

parseValue(item) {
    this.getData.get(item)
    .subscribe((resp) => { 
      // обработка resp;
    return resp
})
```

Если возвращать результаты запроса на сервер, получаю [object Object]

```
parseValue(item) {
    return this.getData.get(item)
    .subscribe((resp) => { 
      // обработка resp;
    return resp
})
```

Comment: [изучите основы rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите так:

```
<span>{{item}} {{parseValue(item) | async}}</span>
```

То функция должна выглядеть как то так:

```
parseValue(item) { return this.getData.get(item); }
```